# I am using JpaRepository in my application.And in Implementation class im calling the findAll(Example<T>) but its not giving me proper response

Tags: java, spring-boot

This is my repository interface

```
public interface InvoiceHeaderRepository extends JpaRepository<InvoiceHeaderDo, Integer>{
}
```

And this the function where I'm calling the findAll(Example).

```
    public List<InvoiceHeaderDto> filterByKeys(InvoiceHeaderDto dto) {
        ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
        List<InvoiceHeaderDto> dtoList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Example<InvoiceHeaderDo> example = Example.of(importDto(dto));
            List<InvoiceHeaderDo> entityList = invoiceHeaderRepository.findAll(example);
            for (InvoiceHeaderDo invoiceHeaderDo : entityList) {
                dtoList.add(mapper.map(invoiceHeaderDo, InvoiceHeaderDto.class));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dtoList;
    }
```

And I have getter setter in my Entity Class.So when Im hitting from postman its not working and automatically taking one parameter which I'm not passing from postman.This the an object of this Entity.

```
{
        "requestId": "APA-000001",
        "compCode": 11,
        "refDocNum": 4500000842,
        "extInvNum": "410E02035B",
        "createdAt": 1519948800000,
        "clerkId": null,
        "clerkEmail": null,
        "channelType": null,
        "refDocCat": null,
        "invoiceType": "Invoice",
        "invoiceTotal": "33300.84",
        "sapInvoiceNumber": null,
        "fiscalYear": null,
        "currency": "USD",
        "paymentTerms": null,
        "taxAmount": null,
        "shippingCost": 55.0,
        "lifecycleStatus": null,
        "taskStatus": null,
        "version": null,
        "emailFrom": null,
        "vendorId": 14775
    }
```

So when I'm trying to filter on like this

```
{
    "requestId": "APA-000001"
}
```

its giving empty list.
This is the log where its taking another field also.

```
2020-03-12T05:06:24.681+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Hibernate: 
2020-03-12T05:06:24.681+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     select
2020-03-12T05:06:24.681+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT         invoicehea0_.request_id as request_id1_1_,
2020-03-12T05:06:24.681+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT         invoicehea0_.vendor_id as vendor_id2_1_,
2020-03-12T05:06:24.681+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT         invoicehea0_.channel_type as channel_type3_1_,
2020-03-12T05:06:24.681+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT         invoicehea0_.clerk_email as clerk_email4_1_,
2020-03-12T05:06:24.681+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT         invoicehea0_.clerk_id as clerk_id5_1_,
2020-03-12T05:06:24.681+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT         invoicehea0_.comp_code as comp_code6_1_,
2020-03-12T05:06:24.681+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT         invoicehea0_.created_at as created_at7_1_,
2020-03-12T05:06:24.681+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT         invoicehea0_.currency as currency8_1_,
2020-03-12T05:06:24.681+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT         invoicehea0_.email_from as email_from9_1_,
2020-03-12T05:06:24.681+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT         invoicehea0_.ext_inv_num as ext_inv_num10_1_,
2020-03-12T05:06:24.681+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT         invoicehea0_.fiscal_year as fiscal_year11_1_,
2020-03-12T05:06:24.681+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT         invoicehea0_.invoice_total as invoice_total12_1_,
2020-03-12T05:06:24.681+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT         invoicehea0_.invoice_type as invoice_type13_1_,
2020-03-12T05:06:24.681+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT         invoicehea0_.lifecycle_status as lifecycle_status14_1_,
2020-03-12T05:06:24.681+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT         invoicehea0_.payment_terms as payment_terms15_1_,
2020-03-12T05:06:24.681+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT         invoicehea0_.ref_doc_cat as ref_doc_cat16_1_,
2020-03-12T05:06:24.681+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT         invoicehea0_.ref_doc_num as ref_doc_num17_1_,
2020-03-12T05:06:24.681+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT         invoicehea0_.sap_invoice_number as sap_invoice_number18_1_,
2020-03-12T05:06:24.681+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT         invoicehea0_.shipping_cost as shipping_cost19_1_,
2020-03-12T05:06:24.681+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT         invoicehea0_.task_status as task_status20_1_,
2020-03-12T05:06:24.681+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT         invoicehea0_.tax_amount as tax_amount21_1_,
2020-03-12T05:06:24.681+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT         invoicehea0_.version as version22_1_ 
2020-03-12T05:06:24.681+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     from
2020-03-12T05:06:24.681+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT         apautomation.invoice_header invoicehea0_ 
2020-03-12T05:06:24.681+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     where
2020-03-12T05:06:24.681+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT         invoicehea0_.request_id=? 
2020-03-12T05:06:24.681+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT         and invoicehea0_.ref_doc_num=0
```

this is my Controller

```
@PostMapping("/filter")
    public List<InvoiceHeaderDto> filterGetAll(@RequestBody InvoiceHeaderDto dto){
        return headerService.filterByKeys(dto);
    }
```

Here is the Entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Invoice_Header")
public class InvoiceHeaderDo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "InvoiceHeader")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "InvoiceHeader", strategy = "com.incture.ap.sequences.InvoiceHeaderSequenceGenerator", parameters = {
            @Parameter(name = InvoiceHeaderSequenceGenerator.INCREMENT_PARAM, value = "1"), @Parameter(name = InvoiceHeaderSequenceGenerator.VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER, value = "APA-"),
            @Parameter(name = InvoiceHeaderSequenceGenerator.NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER, value = "%06d"),
            @Parameter(name = InvoiceHeaderSequenceGenerator.SEQUENCE_PARAM,value="INVOICE_HEADER_SEQ")})

    @Column(name="REQUEST_ID")
    private String requestId;
    @Column(name="COMP_CODE")
    private Integer compCode;
    @Column(name="REF_DOC_NUM")
    private long refDocNum;
    @Column(name="EXT_INV_NUM")
    private String extInvNum;
    @Column(name="CREATED_AT")
    private Date createdAt;
    @Column(name="VENDOR_ID")
    private Integer VendorId;
    @Column(name="CLERK_ID")
    private Integer clerkId;
    @Column(name="CLERK_EMAIL")
    private String clerkEmail;
    @Column(name="CHANNEL_TYPE")
    private String channelType;
    @Column(name="REF_DOC_CAT")
    private String refDocCat;
    @Column(name="INVOICE_TYPE")
    private String invoiceType;
    @Column(name="INVOICE_TOTAL")
    private String invoiceTotal;
    @Column(name="SAP_INVOICE_NUMBER")
    private Integer sapInvoiceNumber;
    @Column(name="FISCAL_YEAR")
    private String fiscalYear;
    @Column(name="CURRENCY")
    private String currency;
    @Column(name="PAYMENT_TERMS")
    private String paymentTerms;
    @Column(name="TAX_AMOUNT")
    private Integer taxAmount;
    @Column(name="SHIPPING_COST")
    private Double shippingCost;
    @Column(name="LIFECYCLE_STATUS")
    private String lifecycleStatus;
    @Column(name="TASK_STATUS")
    private String taskStatus;
    @Column(name="VERSION")
    private Integer version;
    @Column(name="EMAIL_FROM")
    private String emailFrom;
```

here is the dto

```
public class InvoiceHeaderDto {

    private String requestId;

    private Integer compCode;

    private long refDocNum;

    private String extInvNum;

    private Date createdAt;

    private Integer VendorId;

    private Integer clerkId;

    private String clerkEmail;

    private String channelType;

    private String refDocCat;

    private String invoiceType;

    private String invoiceTotal;

    private Integer sapInvoiceNumber;

    private String fiscalYear;

    private String currency;

    private String paymentTerms;

    private Integer taxAmount;

    private Double shippingCost;

    private String lifecycleStatus;

    private String taskStatus;

    private Integer version;

    private String emailFrom;

    public String getRequestId() {
        return requestId;
    }

    public void setRequestId(String requestId) {
        this.requestId = requestId;
    }

    public Integer getCompCode() {
        return compCode;
    }

    public void setCompCode(Integer compCode) {
        this.compCode = compCode;
    }



    public long getRefDocNum() {
        return refDocNum;
    }

    public void setRefDocNum(long refDocNum) {
        this.refDocNum = refDocNum;
    }

    public String getExtInvNum() {
        return extInvNum;
    }

    public void setExtInvNum(String extInvNum) {
        this.extInvNum = extInvNum;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Integer getVendorId() {
        return VendorId;
    }

    public void setVendorId(Integer vendorId) {
        VendorId = vendorId;
    }

    public Integer getClerkId() {
        return clerkId;
    }

    public void setClerkId(Integer clerkId) {
        this.clerkId = clerkId;
    }

    public String getClerkEmail() {
        return clerkEmail;
    }

    public void setClerkEmail(String clerkEmail) {
        this.clerkEmail = clerkEmail;
    }

    public String getChannelType() {
        return channelType;
    }

    public void setChannelType(String channelType) {
        this.channelType = channelType;
    }

    public String getRefDocCat() {
        return refDocCat;
    }

    public void setRefDocCat(String refDocCat) {
        this.refDocCat = refDocCat;
    }

    public String getInvoiceType() {
        return invoiceType;
    }

    public void setInvoiceType(String invoiceType) {
        this.invoiceType = invoiceType;
    }

    public String getInvoiceTotal() {
        return invoiceTotal;
    }

    public void setInvoiceTotal(String invoiceTotal) {
        this.invoiceTotal = invoiceTotal;
    }

    public Integer getSapInvoiceNumber() {
        return sapInvoiceNumber;
    }

    public void setSapInvoiceNumber(Integer sapInvoiceNumber) {
        this.sapInvoiceNumber = sapInvoiceNumber;
    }

    public String getFiscalYear() {
        return fiscalYear;
    }

    public void setFiscalYear(String fiscalYear) {
        this.fiscalYear = fiscalYear;
    }

    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    public String getPaymentTerms() {
        return paymentTerms;
    }

    public void setPaymentTerms(String paymentTerms) {
        this.paymentTerms = paymentTerms;
    }

    public Integer getTaxAmount() {
        return taxAmount;
    }

    public void setTaxAmount(Integer taxAmount) {
        this.taxAmount = taxAmount;
    }

    public Double getShippingCost() {
        return shippingCost;
    }

    public void setShippingCost(Double shippingCost) {
        this.shippingCost = shippingCost;
    }

    public String getLifecycleStatus() {
        return lifecycleStatus;
    }

    public void setLifecycleStatus(String lifecycleStatus) {
        this.lifecycleStatus = lifecycleStatus;
    }

    public String getTaskStatus() {
        return taskStatus;
    }

    public void setTaskStatus(String taskStatus) {
        this.taskStatus = taskStatus;
    }

    public Integer getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Integer version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getEmailFrom() {
        return emailFrom;
    }

    public void setEmailFrom(String emailFrom) {
        this.emailFrom = emailFrom;
    }
```

Comment: in the findAll query I see there is one more extra param ref_doc_num? Can you share  InvoiceHeaderDo class also

Comment: Example.of(T proble) Create a new Example including all non-null properties by default. As already mentioned by @Pulkit the refDocNum is probably not null

Comment: @Pulkit shared.

Comment: @pero_hero no it is not not null

Comment: can you add the InvoiceHeaderDto class/constructor and what the method import(dto) does?

Comment: Can you try once by changing long to Long for ref_doc_num??

Comment: @Pulkit Yeah I thought of doin that also.

Comment: @pero_hero its just copy of the entity and the importDto(dto) is checking the fields if not null setting to the entity.

Comment: Let us know if this works for you

Comment: Yeah long was the issue.@Pulkit thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, you are searching not only by `id` but by some `ref_doc_num`as well. Because it is of type `long` it cannot be `null` but will be `0` uponi init. That results in additional predicate in query and obvious mismatch, as presented entity data does not contain `ref_doc_num==0`

```
 @Column(name="REF_DOC_NUM")
    private long refDocNum;

2020-03-12T05:06:24.681+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     where
2020-03-12T05:06:24.681+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT         invoicehea0_.request_id=? 
2020-03-12T05:06:24.681+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT         and invoicehea0_.ref_doc_num=0
```

Try changing `refDocNum` to `Long` to allow null values.

Pro tip of the day: Use start using [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) to avoid boilerplate code.